# How to redirect StandardInput of existing process

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have 2 executable files, out of which one my files calls the third party executable which opens the chrome  and another of my 2nd executable which use the above opened process id and try to set url to chrome

Assume that first executable opened process id is "13265"

Here is my sample code:

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessById(13265);     
StreamWriter myStreamWriter = p.StandardInput;
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("https://www.google.com/");
```

The above code throws error like "`StandardIn` has not been redirected."

Comment: Could be an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve? There might be a better way.

Comment: Per https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18577/How-to-redirect-Standard-Input-Output-of-an-applic it looks like you need to set `processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true`.  See article for more info.

Comment: John, in your article it starts the process from scratch but for me it is not , have to use existing process

Comment: @marsze, i have one third party AutoIT exe which accepts mutiple std input (like open browser , redirect url , capture element on browser) , i can able to starts this exe from my exe and able to overwrites the std inputs dynamically (after process starts)
but my requirement is like call this AutoIT exe for open empty browser in one exe and then use this above process in another exe and forced to chage the std input like redirect url

Comment: I am also looking for something, how did you resolve this issue?